# R: Code runs and creates too big of a file, how should I change?

Tags: r

perhaps I am misunderstanding exactly how this code works. My original data had 18102x7 = 126,714 entries in it. Shouldn't my new csv file have 18102x8 = 144,816 entries in it because I created a new column of ID's? why would it spit out 327 million? Any help here would be much appreciated.

```
 mydata<-read.csv("data.csv")


dd<-data.frame(mydata[,1:3], 
               X4=letters[mydata[,4]], X5=mydata[,5], 
               matrix(runif(nrow(mydata)*(18102-ncol(mydata))), nrow=nrow(mydata)))

dd$ID <- as.numeric(interaction(dd[,1:5], drop=T, lex.order=T))


write.csv(dd,file="newdata.csv")
```

Comment: `interaction` will create a factor with as many levels as there are in the product of the number unique items in each of the first 5 columns of `dd`. This might be a case where you are attempting to do `<something>` but not telling us what it is so we cannot help.

Comment: If you just want to create an ID, then perhaps `apply(dd,1,paste0)`

Comment: @BondedDust But ultimately `d$ID` will be the name length as the input. Assuming you get to the point where you write the file, there's no reason to expect a change in output that large, right? If the interaction is to big, i would have expected an error about "cannot allocate vector..." from the `interaction` call.

Comment: Ya got me. No data, no code to describe the result in the R session. Who knows?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to R and may be leaving out information that would be helpful in solving this. When I run this with larger sets of data, Rstudio gives me an error along the lines of "cannot establish connection to R session." When I reduce the size of the data down to a smaller size (like this one), it writes a 5.5 GB CSV file. @BondedDust, the end result of the program is to assign the same ID-number to rows of data with the same first 5 columns. The data has both words (i.e. Which state a row belongs to) and numerical data (ie: number of people).

Comment: I have experience using MATLAB, and I know the MATLAB code would essentially work by choosing a particular row and looping through all the other rows, checking if the first five columns are the same. If the first 5 columns are the same, then it would store it in a temporary matrix, assigning those rows in the temporary matrix the same ID-number. However, I was having trouble translating this method to R, and @MrFlick was very helpful in suggesting I use interaction. This method works very well for small sets of data (20 rows), but creates files that very large for larger sets of data

Comment: I don't really understand how interaction() works, or how these factor levels come into play, which may be helpful in my further understanding the problem and finding a solution. Again thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AddisonWright I still can't imagine a scenario where using `interaction` like this would create any additional rows. Unless we can recreate the problem, it's hard to say what's going on.